# Ubiqutous font on linux plaform

Tags: fonts

I am using `Xlib' to query fonts available on linux machine. A string is sent to the machine (similar to 'xfontsel'). To my surprise even the following is not available on some linux machine.

```
"-misc-fixed-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"
```

I want to make sure that user does not have to install any fonts to use my application. Is there any font which is (nearly) guaranteed to be available on all linux machine?

Answer (score 3):

The X core fonts subsystem has been deprecated for years under Linux (it was replaced by fontconfig-based font stacks, and fontconfig is about a decade old).

It's still kept as a compatibility measure in most distributions, but is also slowly been ripped out (starting with font collections). Besides most distributions have announced they will be deprecating X11, and the first thing the replacements (wayland, mir) got rid of was the X core fonts system (because most GUI applications have been switched to fontconfig a long time ago).

So to answer your question: the most common fonts under Linux nowadays are the DejaVu fonts (near complete penetration as measured by codestyle when they still bothered with font surveys). They are usually not exposed in the X core fonts subsystem but always in fontconfig. Even when they are not present fontconfig has a nice aliasing system where the 'sans' 'serif' and 'monospace' aliases will always exist and point to the best font available. The state of the X core font system on the other hand will vary greatly among Linux distributions, from complete to vestigial and you can not rely on any specific font existing in it (or even on the core fonts subsystem existing at all).

Do yourself and your users a favor, switch your application to the font system everyone else uses before the font system it relies on is completely forgotten. Your problem is not the font to use, your problem is the whole software stack you depend on is being killed right now.

If you don't want to learn the particulars of all the libraries which are necessary to process modern smart fonts, just use pango. It provides a stable interface to all the components (fontconfig, freetype, freebidi, harfbuzz, and I probably forget some, new ones are added each year as font formats become more intricate) required to process unicode opentype fonts.

http://behdad.org/text/